# Plot cannot opened in python laucher in Mac

Tags: python, macos

I'm following the **[Pyplot tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html)** and I wanted to create a plot in **Python IDLE** 2.7.10 Shell. During the code execution, the python launcher has been called. However, the launcher just 'jump' and 'jump' again, but it connot open to show the plot.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
```

**Environment**

> Mac OSX version : 10.10.5
>   Python version : 2.7.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display it, add `plt.show()`